# My count(*) function isn't returning correct values

Tags: mysql, sql

Im supposed to Write a query that displays only the major
and the number of students in each major even for majors with no students

```
select S.first_name, m.major ,count(*) as 'Number of Majors '
from student S
inner join advisor_student SA on S._SID_ = SA.SID
right join major m on  SA.MID_ = m._MID_
group by major;
```

Comment: Invalid group by. Won't execute on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), may return unpredictable results with older MySQL versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: RIGHT JOIN? Most people find "main table left join optional data" easier to understand than "optional data right join main table".

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (Formatted text, please. Not images.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use left join to student table and you shouldn't fetch student name, unless if you don't you concatenate it.

```
select  m.major ,count(s.first_name)+ count(sa.first_name) as 'Number of Majors '
from major m
left join advisor_student SA on S._SID_ = SA.SID
left join student s on  S.MID_ = m._MID_
group by major;
```

Comment: What is this `count(s.first_name)+ count(sa.first_name)` supposed to calculate?

Comment: As I understood ,advisor students and regular students are saved in different tables. So i get the counts of each and then i sum up the total

Comment: It's joining *major -> advisor_student -> student*, so `advisor_student` is probably an associative table. And if your assumption was true it might result in a many-many-join with way too many rows multiplying the counts.

Answer (score 0):

No need to join the students:

```
select m.major
   -- count(*) returns 1 for majors without student
   -- must count a column from the inner table which is NOT NULL
   -- usually done using the join column
   ,count(SA.MID_) as 'Number of Majors '
from major m
left join advisor_student SA 
  on  SA.MID_ = m._MID_
group by major;
```